# Get Persistent Volume Source from inside Java Application

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, datadog, kubernetes-pvc

I have a java application that is deployed in a kubernetes cluster and logs to DataDog.We want to add a custom attribute to our logs, which is the server host of the PV/PVCs it's reading data from. Is that possible from inside the java code? Please feel free to ask for any more information you might need.
Thank you

Comment: That doesn't seem like it's information that the application could have access to, even using paths like the downward API.  It also depends heavily on the "kind" of the volume; what value would you expect to be logged for a `local` volume, vs. an NFS store, vs. something like an EBS volume?

Comment: Our application is run internally and all volumes are of the same kind. We want to filter and check all logs for a specific server in datadog if that makes sense. We have a custom wrapper on logback json logger, so In case of local volumes or volumes without a server, we can have an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to get this information via the kubernetes API? For example, if you use the `kubectl` cli and call `kubectl get pvc my-pvc -o yaml`, is the information you need available there? If so, one way of doing it might be to query the API directly inside your application (or even from a sidecar or initContainer on the same pod). See also https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/